# Design bug: Profiles empty whitespace

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I am sure this is not intended, I am seeing a lot of whitespace on user profiles

(**Note:** the image is zoomed out)

[image]

**FireFox 10.0.2 on Windows XP**

Comment: I hope is not a repost...

Comment: reproduced in Google Chrome 17.0.963.83 (stable) on OS X 10.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will be fixed in the next production build.